# Count rows in Aggrid Angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

When I charge datas, the rows shows 0 totals 0 selects, but If I select 1 row then I can see 4 rows 1select, I don't understand why when the application charge doesn't count the rows..

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http.get(this.config.getUrl('myProject')).subscribe(data => {
      this.columnDefs = data['headers'];
      this.rowData = data['datas'];
      this.countOnSelectionChanged(); //here
    });
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
```

I check join the function `console.log and totalResults = 0`

```
countOnSelectionChanged() {
    console.log('here');
    this.selectedResults = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows().length;

    this.totalResults = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount();

    console.log('totalResults', this.totalResults);
    console.log('selectedResults', this.selectedResults);
  }
```

Then when I do click in checkbox

```
 onSelectionChanged() {
    this.countOnSelectionChanged();
    this.enableAssociatedActions();
  }
```

I call again the function countOnSelectionChanged and now , totalResults = 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that the row count displays '0 totals' directly after you loaded the data.
I think that the api isn't ready i.e. the grid doesn't display the data, when you first call `this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()`. You could instead listen for the `rowDataChanged` grid event and then call this method.
[Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/):
`rowDataChanged`:   The client has set new data into the grid using api.setRowData() or changing the rowData bound property.

template:

```
<ag-grid-angular (rowDataChanged)="countDisplayedRows($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

ts:

```
countDisplayedRows(params) {
  this.totalResults = params.api.getDisplayedRowCount();
}
```